# Can't access to schema in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

Lets say that I made this "simple" implementation of a DB in Postgres

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE my_role;
           CREATE DATABASE my_db;
           GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_db TO my_role;
           CREATE SCHEMA my_schm AUTHORIZATION my_role;
```

And then I want to make a table:

```
postgres=#CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST my_db.my_schm.table(...);
```

And got the following error: 
`cross-database references are not implemented: "my_db.my_schm.table"`

After this, I tried to create the table connected to the db (i.e. `\c my_db`) and got the following error:

```
schema "my_schm"does not exist
```

So, I don't understand the behavior from these errors, It is supposed that the role have all permissions to the db (and yes, I also tried using `SET ROLE my_role;`) but when I ask to show the schemas in my_db indeed my_schm doesn't exist, but in Postgres it does. Can someone explain to me please why is this happening? And also how can group the tables in my_schm?

Comment: why not `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST my_db.table(...);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schemas exist only in one single database and are created in the *current* database: you have created your schema in `postgres` database not in `mydb`.

You need to connect first to `mydb` database in order to create the schema in `mydb` database.